# Finding difference in dates which is in format "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I have a two dates in date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" format. How to find the difference and how to check whether the difference is more than 4 hours?

This is how i have tried

```
echo $(( ( $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") - $(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S" -d "1970-01-01 + $(stat -c '%Z' filename ) secs"))))
```

date command returns this

```
Sun Sep  6 10:35:19 CDT 2015
```

Comment: If they are truely in `+"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` format you will have to parse them first since the year and month will run together in the string and give an invalid date error when you tryu to read.

Answer (score 4):

Having e.g.:

```
date1=20150906171119
date2=20150906172244
```

a sample /  start could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

date1=20150906171119
date2=20150906172244

# Convert date to YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS and get time in seconds.
d1=$(date -d"${date1:0:8} ${date1:8:2}:${date1:10:2}:${date1:12:2}" +%s)
d2=$(date -d"${date2:0:8} ${date2:8:2}:${date2:10:2}:${date2:12:2}" +%s)

# Limit in seconds
# 60    = 1 min
# 3600  = 1 hour
# 14400 = 4 hours
lim=14400

# arg1=time1 (seconds)
# arg2=time2 (seconds)
# arg3=difference limit
ddiff()
{
    if (($1 > $2)); then
        ddiff $2 $1 $3
    else
        return $(($2 - $1 < $3))
    fi
}

if ddiff $d1 $d2 $lim; then
    echo more then $lim seconds
else
    echo less then $lim seconds
fi
```

You could throw in an equality check, `date1 = date2`, if that is important.

Comment: yea this will help , what if the file is older than 1 day? will this work?

Comment: @VRVigneshwara: You get the time in seconds since Epoch, 1970. As long as you do not have files older then 45 years and 8 months + change, it should not be an issue. But, if the dates differ in time-zones, you'll have unreliable results.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this as there is no timezone in that format.

`"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"`

is the format that is standardized for e.g. `diff -u` and that format includes the timezone.

Comment: This seems like a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Well, it is the answer, note that you cannot compute a difference between two values if you cannot know if one might be using daylight saving time.

Comment: Well, you can ignore DST (presumably both times being compared are from the same system and in the same time zone) and you can parse the string to make it compatible with `date` as Sukminder has shown.

Comment: If you were right, then the old timestamps from the SCCS history files and what was used by early RCS implementations was not a problem. Unfortunately, even or in special two timevalues from the same location that are only a few minutes apart cause the problem when there is a DST switch in between. So you could believe that the second time is 30 minutes before the first while it really was 90 minutes after the first one.

Comment: If you however add %z to the format, you know the GMT offset in minutes and then everything is OK, BTW: this is used in the SCCSv6 history format.

Comment: @terdon, as an example, compare: `TZ=Europe/London date -d@"$((1414284000))" '+%F %T'` with `TZ=Europe/London date -d@"$((1414284000 + 3600))" '+%F %T'` (on a GNU system). See how adding a `%z` helps.

Comment: date does not have a -d option. So this only works on some system with vendor specific enhancements.

Comment: which is why I said _on a GNU system_ (which I know @terdon has access to). Replace with the perl/ksh93/zsh equivalent if on other systems

Comment: Note that the `TZ=Europe/London`, `%F` are not standard either. `TZ=:Europe/London` would be _more POSIX_ but still undefined. Doing portable date manipulation is very hard. Usually, the best approach is to resort to `perl` in my experience.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas and schily OK, I see what you mean. I figured the OP didn't need to consider DST since they only had two dates to compare and it sounded like a localized issue. I agree that you will need to deal with DST for any kind of generalized solution. In any case, the OP is on a GNU system since their date has a `-d` and they've tagged as `linux`. I don't think portability is a requirement here (but, of course, it should always be considered).

Comment: OK, but I already explained why even two time stamps from the same system cannot be compared without a GMT offset being available.